# Explode string into foreach

Tags: php, foreach

I have the following GET parameters:
?data=prop_123&data=prop_124&data=prop_125&data=prop_126&data=prop_129&data=prop_127

I was wondering if anybody knew a quick method of getting each value into a foreach? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This won't work, because all of your parameters have the same name, so only the value "prop_127" is going to be passed to your script.  You can create this as an array instead, like this:

```
?data[]=prop_123&data[]=prop_124&data[]=prop_125&data[]=prop_126&data[]=prop_129&data[]=prop_127
```

And then you can use `foreach()` to loop through them like this:

```
foreach ( $_GET['data'] as $data ) {
    // This loops once for each instance of data[] in your URL
}
```

If you have no control over the URL, you'd have to read it in manually with `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`, then parse through it to pull the values out.

Answer (score 2):

Each `data` will overwrite the previous in `$_GET` or with `parse_str` so something like this maybe:

```
$s = 'data=prop_123&data=prop_124&data=prop_125&data=prop_126&data=prop_129&data=prop_127';
$s = str_replace('=', '[]=', $s);
parse_str($s, $a);

foreach($a as $something) { }
```

If you are actually trying to put the vars in a GET request and can get them from `$_GET`, then use the form `data[]` in the query string and then just `foreach` over `$_GET`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP function: parse_str

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Comment: `parse_str()` will only return the last value just as `$_GET` would, because they all share the same name.

Comment: You are right, I notice this problem after writing the answer :)